# How can we get finger thinkness on touch in ios

Tags: ios, uitouch, fingerprint

I have an application in which I want to detect the thickness of the finger touched with. Or is there any way we can get whether the user has changed who was using the app ?

Please suggest!!

Comment: These sound like two completely different questions. There is no way to detect any sort of touch thickness or pressure. Future phones may have that but not currently.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure that it's possible. TouchID is accessing via LAContext (see https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/LocalAuthentication/Reference/LAContext_Class/index.html) and the only thing you can do is to request authorization and receive success\failure response.

Comment: @ZacharyYoung This is a perfectly valid answer.

Comment: @isherwood This is a perfectly valid answer.